# Prevent logins to unauthorized AAD tenant?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is there a way to prevent users from logging into their own AAD tenants? For example, allow login to `contoso.onmicrosoft.com` but not `fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com`.

My customer has a highly-controlled Azure environment where they are running some servers and PaaS/SaaS applications. Users connect to those servers are use a variety of Azure services and some SaaS (primary concern is PowerBI). They’re concerned that a user could login with a non-company account (wahid@hotmail.com) and then upload sensitive data their own PowerBI workspace.

Comment: If one account was created/invited to one tenant, the user just can login to that tenant. For the scenario you described, I suggest you could revoke the Product license for those users. If you don't assign product license to the user, the user cannot use that App or cannot see that app in My Apps panel. For other SaaS/PaaS app, you may use user assignment to allow specific users to access the App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others: Daniel answered this for me. Short answer, this isn't easy, you would need to inspect the response body for the tenant ID (or name) and then block it. This would also lead to a poor user experience but that's all we can do today.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent a user who has already been in the tenant to login to that AAD tenant, except deleting the user from that tenant.

If one account was created/invited to one tenant, the user just can login to that tenant.

For the scenario you described, I suggest you could revoke the Product license for those users. If you don't assign product license to the user, the user cannot use that App or cannot see that app in My Apps panel. For other SaaS/PaaS app(Web App), you may use user assignment to allow specific users to access the App.

Comment: In my scenario, I don't own the "other" tenant and therefore can't change licensing or user permissions. I simply want to prevent the user from logging into a tenant that doesn't belong to my organization. I can do this for most services (like Azure SQL, Storage, etc.) because they have a URL that can be blocked. I can't seem to find that for Azure AD (to prevent logins to Azure Portal or Office 365 for example).

Comment: Hi,@Wahid. I see. Since you don't own other tenants, you cannaot change the license and you cannot decides which tenant or app could the guest user use. Also, for guest user,he/she cannot login Office 365 portal:-).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a few options.

#### Option 1: Single tenant apps

If you have the ability to create apps in the tenant you want to accept users from, you can mark your app as available to only this tenant (the field is called `availableToOtherTenants`). This will notify the token service to only authorize access from users in the tenant the app was created in.

#### Option 2: Multi-tenant app w/ token validation

The other option is to mark your app as multi-tenant (same field as above, just set to `true`) and implement logic in your app to validate the user's tenant from which the token was issued.

In this scenario, you will need to have some kind of web service that can safely validate access tokens ([.NET code sample on this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect)).  To check the tenant the user's account belongs to, you'll need to validate the `iss` field. It'll look something like this,

`"iss": "https://sts.windows.net/7fe81447-da57-4385-becb-6de57f21477e/"`

in which the GUID represents the tenant ID.  This allows your web API to have an allow or deny list based off tenant IDs.

#### More help

[Here's](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/03/03/principles-of-token-validation/) an excellent blog post on token validation.

[Azure AD Developer Docs](https://aka.ms/aaddev)

[.NET Web API Code Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect)

Comment: Thank you, this is a bit closer to my requirements. But I don't have a specific custom app, it's just the regular Azure services (azure portal, powershell, data lake, etc.).With the method proposed, I basically have to provide a front-end to the Azure API.

Comment: Can you elaborate the medium in which you'd like to validate the user's identity? You may have a few options in terms of letting the user sign in w/o necessarily building a full front end (e.g. Azure CLI sends you a code you enter on a site, then enter your creds).

Comment: To be honest, I don't want to validate their identity. I just don't want them to login to a resource (example, Azure Portal) that I have no control over that would enable them to exfiltrate my data. The normal way to stop this is to whitelist sites that are mine, we can do this with Azure SQL (whitelist myAzureSQL.database.windows.net). If I whitelist portal.azure.com, it allows anyone's Azure. If I whitelist powerbi.com, it allows anyone's PowerBI. This is an AAD concern because both of those examples (Portal/PowerBI) and others use AAD to login.

Comment: Ideally, it would be GREAT if the AAD login page (login.microsoftonline.com included the tenant name, like myTenantXYZ.login.microsoftonline.com). This would enable me to allow myTenantXYZ while blocking others.

Comment: The login url does allow apps you specify a tenant for sign in (eg login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/[...]).  The tricky thing is end users can modify the request, so it’s up to the app (either marking itself as single tenant or through token validation) to verify they signed in from an allowed tenant.

Comment: I’m not understand your exact scenario, would you be interested in hopping on a call and chatting about what you’re trying to accomplish? If so, my email address is on my stackoverflow profile.

Comment: For others: Daniel answered this for me. Short answer, this isn't easy, you would need to inspect the response body for the tenant ID (or name) and then block it. This would also lead to a poor user experience but that's all we can do today.